# GridView in asp.net c# with paging

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have problem on a GridView in asp net c# with paging

This GridView is populated with the query where is called one value passed in querystring.

In first bind the output in GridView is correct, but when I try on change page the GridView response with below error.

```
Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not 
set to an instance of an object.
```

In this line in **public DataTable GridViewBind()**

```
throw ex;
```

I think that the error is caused from the value in querystring that is lost in reloading the page.

My code below, I would greatly appreciate any help you can give me in working this problem.

```
public DataTable GridViewBind()
{
        sql = " SELECT * from tbl_premium WHERE Year_month = ?; ";

    try
    {
        dadapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(sql, conn);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["Year_month"].ToString()))
        {
            dadapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("param1", Request.QueryString["Year_month"].ToString());
        }

        dset = new DataSet();
        dset.Clear();
        dadapter.Fill(dset);
        DataTable dt = dset.Tables[0];
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;

        GridView1.DataBind();
        return dt;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        dadapter.Dispose();
        dadapter = null;
        conn.Close();
    }
}


protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewBind();
    GridView1.DataSource = dset.Tables[0];
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    GridView1.DataBind();

}

protected void ddlPages_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow gvrPager = GridView1.BottomPagerRow;
    DropDownList ddlPages = (DropDownList)gvrPager.Cells[0].FindControl("ddlPages");
    GridViewBind();
    GridView1.DataSource = dset.Tables[0];
    GridView1.PageIndex = ddlPages.SelectedIndex;
    GridView1.DataBind();

}

protected void Paginate(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    int intCurIndex = GridView1.PageIndex;

    switch (e.CommandArgument.ToString().ToLower())
    {
        case "First":
            GridView1.PageIndex = 0;
            break;
        case "Prev":
            GridView1.PageIndex = intCurIndex - 1;
            break;
        case "Next":
            GridView1.PageIndex = intCurIndex + 1;
            break;
        case "Last":
            GridView1.PageIndex = GridView1.PageCount - 1;
            break;
    }
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Tell us exactly what line the error occurs on, so we don't have to guess. Also, I see you have this line `GridView1.DataSource = dset.Tables[0];` but you don't show the initialization of the `dset` object anywhere.

Comment: Get rid of the `catch(Exception ex){throw ex;}`. All that does is mess up your stack trace. It will look like the exception came from _that_ line. It does you no good. Get rid of it.

Comment: You have a `catch` block but no `try` block.

Comment: I'm sorry, error on copy/paste. I have edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, this line:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["Year_month"].ToString()))
```

is running into an exception.

> Please make sure you pass `Year_month` as a parameter in your paging url so that it works when re-binding the gridview.

Another thing that you may try, (as a fail-safe) is to check if `Request.QueryString["Year_month"]` is not `NULL`. Try to convert it to String value only if it is not null.

Comment: But in first bind the gridview is populated with values extracted with variable querystring, why when change page I have error ? thank you you

Comment: For paging, we generally pass parameter as page number and also all the parameters from the parent page, in your case, Year_month. See if the paging url that forms is like `view.aspx?Year_month=value&page=2`